# Condensing logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Simplify:
>   $2\log_{10}\sqrt{x}+3\log_{10}x^{\frac{1}{3}}$

I got to this: $2\log_{10}x^{\frac{1}{2}}+3\log_{10}x^{\frac{1}{3}}$.

Now, usually you bring the exponent the the front and that would yield:

$$\frac{1}{2}(2)\log_{10}x+\frac{1}{3}(3)\log_{10}x=\log_{10}x+\log_{10}x=2\log_{10}x$$

And that's it?

Comment: Check your arithmetic: $\frac12(2)\ne 2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \frac{1}{2}(2)\log_{10}x+\frac{1}{3}(3)\log_{10}x \neq 2\log_{10}x+3\log_{10}x$$

$1/2 * 2 = 1$ so do $1/3 * 3.$

So the correct thing is
$$\frac{1}{2}(2)\log_{10}x+\frac{1}{3}(3)\log_{10}x = \log_{10}x+\log_{10}x = 2\log_{10}x$$
Bring the exponent inside the $\log$ if you like.

**The other way around:** bring $1/2$ into $\log_{10} \sqrt{x}$ to become $\log_{10} \sqrt{x}^2 = ??.$